# How does one effectively/safely clean-out or wash their belly button to prevent omphalolith-umbolith (navel stones)?

Tags: hygiene, cotton-swabs-q-tips, navel-belly-button

This may sound silly, but a few weeks ago, I received a gag gift in a White Elephant gift exchange and received a belly button brush brush like this: [image]

It was good for a few laughs, but it got me thinking... When was the last time I've ever cleaned my belly button? For reals? **And how do you clean your belly button specifically? I wash with soap and water around my abdomen, but do I need to do something more?** I shower every day like most people, but is that enough?

The person who gifted me with the novelty item of a belly button brush, recently posted [this article about omphalolith, umbolith, navel stones](http://www.upi.com/Odd_News/2016/08/23/Woman-removes-rock-like-object-from-her-belly-button/5591471957577/) onto my facebook to make me squirm and maybe laugh?

And while I found this [YouTube video about omphaloliths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFskGRZmIBA), that confirms that this indeed happens... Neither the article ^ or the video ^ explained how to **properly clean your own belly button. Or how often.** *Or explained how that impacted dirt starts growing its own hair?*

Comment: Also, for a very practical answer to your question --- just use a Q-tip or cotton swab with water and soap on it and wiggle it around to loosen up the dirt and pull out the yuck. It's actually really effective --- I never thought about it or tried until yesterday when I saw this post. haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never heard of these things and never had them.  I had to find out what they are and came across an article in [Volume 21 - Issue 7 - July 2013 edition](http://www.the-dermatologist.com/issue/2724) of The Dermatologist.

[The article](http://www.the-dermatologist.com/content/what-black-umbilical-nodule) says that

> An omphalolith – also referred to as an omphalith, omphalokeratolith or umbolith – is a keratin and sebum containing stone-like mass found in the umbilicus.

[Sebum](https://www.verywell.com/what-is-sebum-1069375) is a light yellow, oily substance secreted by the sebaceous glands that keep the skin and hair moisturised, and as indicated in the Dermatologist article, these solid masses are a result of poor hygiene.  The hair shown in some pictures is hair from the umbilicus.  It is not something the omphalith is growing.

If you shower or have a bath regularly and ensure the [umbilicus is clean](http://www.prevention.com/health/healthy-living/how-clean-your-belly-button) whilst washing, you should have no problem.